# Twilio android sdk increased app size 36 MB can it be reduced?

Tags: android, twilio

My app size was 26MB before integrating below list of dependency and jar files in my project. But after adding these it is now 62MB. can it be reduced in any possible way?

Build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.twilio:client-android:1.2.14'
compile 'com.twilio:conversations-android:0.12.1'
```

libs folder:

```
ion-2.1.8.jar
koushikdutta-async-2.1.8.jar
```

Please help your reply world be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found very good solution that can split apk with `Minimum` size possible:

I added following code in my `build.gradle` file and now my app maximum size is `28MB(Reduced from 62MB)`.

```
splits {
         density {
             enable true
             exclude "ldpi", "tvdpi", "xxxhdpi"
             compatibleScreens 'small', 'normal', 'large', 'xlarge'
         }

        abi {
            enable true
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a', 'x86_64'
            exclude "armeabi", "mips", "mips64"
            universalApk true
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

Both [`client-android`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android) and [`conversations-android`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/sdks#android-sdk) use native libraries internally(A shared library `*.so` per Android architecture). As a result, by default the APK will consume the `.aar` with the shared libraries for all architectures.

You can look at http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits#TOC-Variant-API-Version-Code-support for more general information.

Here is a gist someone posted with an example of doing ABI splits:
https://gist.github.com/ph0b/69586260bc20c58136ef

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to @Delgado's answer, you can use Proguard to reduce your apk size significantly, if you're not using it yet.

Read more about Proguard [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/shrink-code.html)

Proguard rules for Twilio, as in the [Twilio docs](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android#proguard-exception) suggested by @Delgado :

```
-keep class com.twilio.** { *; }
```

Comment: Please add the following if you plan to use proguard. We have Parcelable objects that can get corrupted with Proguard enabled. https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/client/android#proguard-exception